# C++ contador de palabras de un fichero

Tags: c++, while, contador

tengo que hacer un contador de palabras en `c++` y luego sacar el promedio. Soy muy novata y tengo un problema con el bucle **while** que nunca termina.

¿Alguien puede guiarme o decirme que esta mal en mi código y como sigo adelante?

Mi idea fue contar espacios en blanco y sumarle 1 para que me cuente las palabras en el fichero.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string palabras;
    char espacio_b; //Defino como 
    char los espacios en blanco
    ifstream archivo; //Elijo el archivo txt
    int cantpalabras = 0; //Defino una variable de tipo entero para contar las palabras y defino que empiece en el numero '0'

    archivo.open("frases_bjarme.txt"); //Abro el archivo
    getline(archivo, palabras);
    archivo.close(); //Cierro el archivo
    archivo.get(espacio_b); //Lee los espacios en blanco porque el char lee uno. Por lo que la variable 'palabras' no va a tener ese espacio

    if(archivo.is_open()){ //Verifica que exista el archivo
       archivo>>espacio_b;
}

    while(espacio_b!=0){

     getline(archivo, palabras);
     archivo.get(espacio_b);
     cantpalabras++; //Esto es igual a poner cantpalabras:cantpalabras+1

     cout<<"La cantidad de palabras es igual a: " <<cantpalabras+1<< endl;

     archivo>>espacio_b;

     }


   {
       archivo.close(); //Cierro el archivo

   }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Que quieres decir con sacar el promedio?

Comment: Hola! Me refiero a contar el total de las palabras del archivo txt y dividirlas.

Comment: dividirlas entre que numero?, explicate bien, no has aclarado nada

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo. Eso sí lo he aclarado. Asi que paciencia. Para sacar un promedio se tienen que sumar todas las palabras y hay que dividir el resultado por la cantidad total de palabras que sean. Saludos y gracias por comentar.

Answer (score 1):

Para leer palabras lo mejor es usar el operador de extracción:

```
std::string palabra;
archivo >> palabra;
```

Este operador **descarta automáticamente los espacios en blanco**, saltos de línea y tabuladores.

Por otro lado, el bucle no sale nunca porque en ningún sitio pone que `archivo` guarde un 0 en `espacio_b` cuando se alcanza el final del mismo. En cambio **sí** que pone que se activa el flag `EOF`.

Lo que sucede con este flag es que se activa tras la primera lectura sucia, así que o bien tenemos en cuenta esta circunstancia a la hora de sumar:

```
std::string palabra;
archivo >> palabra;
while (!archivo.eof())
{
    cant_palabras++;
    archivo >> palabra;
}
```

O bien restamos 1 al contador:

```
while (!archivo.eof())
{
    std::string palabra;
    archivo >> palabra;
    cant_palabras++;
}

cant_palabras--;
```

Comment: Lo voy a probar con esas modificaciones que me indicas eferion. Gracias!

Comment: Y como hallaría ese famoso promedio al que se refiere el usuario

Comment: @Japv si saco ese dato ya le hago el ejercicio al completo. En cualquier caso la parte que no funcionaba era el cálculo de líneas, el promedio no lo tiene implementado, ni bien ni mal, simplementeno está.

Comment: @Japv además,  de qué sería el promedio? Palabras por archivo? Palabras por línea? Palabras por X?

Comment: Para sacar un promedio se tienen que sumar todas las palabras y hay que dividir el resultado por la cantidad total de palabras que sean. Saludos y gracias por comentar.

Comment: Lo digo OTRA VEZ, estoy aprendiendo. No se muchas cosas. mi sintaxis es pobre y desprolija pero estoy esforzandome. El tema del calculo del promedio no está en mi codigo porque estoy trabada con el contador de palabras entonces no llegué hasta ahi. Solamente lo mencioné pero no busco que nadie lo haga por mí, simplemente que me expliquen como mejorar y como poder lograr el objetivo. Si está o no bien la sintaxis de mi codigo y que me falta para que el contador funcione. Saludos y gracias por comentar.

Comment: @0111-f nadie se ha metido contigo, luego el ultimo comentario sobra. En cuanto a lo del promedio, tampoco era un comentario dirigido para ti. Y lo del promedio tampoco era un comentario para ti. Si tengo que hacerte preguntas comento en tu pregunta, no en mi propia respuesta (si tengo dudas no respondo). En cualquier caso, la vida es así de cruel, C++ no va a relajar su temperamento por ti. Así que mi consejo es que dejes de poner tu lastima por bandera porque eso no te va a ayudar a dominar el lenguaje, más bien todo lo contrario.

Comment: y lee con tranquilidad los comentarios, no vaya a suceder que te estés metiendo en una conversación ajena y digas cosas que no vienen a cuento. Sí, justo como acaba de pasar. En cualquier caso, y con esto doy por zanjado cualquier asunto, mi intención nunca jamás va a ser resolver tu ejercicio ya que así no vas a aprender. Yo te resuelvo las dudas de la forma más didáctica posible. En este caso tu ejercicio no tiene nada del promedio y, por tanto, yo no hago nada sobre ese tema

Comment: Le estaba respondiendo al otro usuario @Japv. No era para que vos te hagas cargo de lo que dije, porque justamente vos no te metiste con el tema del promedio. Pero mi contestacion nunca fue para vos. Tampoco sé porque mencionas o me das consejos cuando no te los pedi. Que quiero poner mi lastima como bandera? Perdon? El que deberia leer los.comentarios con mas tranquilidad sos vos.

Comment: @Gotita11 en ese caso te pido disculpas. En cualquier caso recuerda que si comentas en la pregunta/respuesta de alguien y no citas a nadie con @, entonces se entiende que el destinatario por defecto es el autor de dicha pregunta/respuesta